# REST API GET - difference in Invoke-Rest method and browser

Tags: rest, powershell

I am using REST API, I encounter problem that in powershell Invoke-RestMethod with -Method GET is returning different values than exact same request in browser.

Output from browser:

```
@odata.count    3
value   
0   
Name    "Administrator"
DisplayName "Administrator"
Groups  
IsStatic    true
Id  3
1   
Name    "awesomeRole"
DisplayName "awesomeRole"
Groups  
IsStatic    false
Id  5
2   
Name    "Robot"
DisplayName "Robot"
Groups  
IsStatic    true
Id  4`
```

output from powershell:

```
Name        : Administrator
DisplayName : Administrator
Groups      : 
IsStatic    : True
Id          : 1
Name        : Robot
DisplayName : Robot
Groups      : 
IsStatic    : True
Id          : 2`
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Hi! You may want to add more details into the question, so that we can help you better.

Comment: I edited post with outputs i got.

Comment: @Frederigo Use a tool like Fiddler to inspect the requests your 2 clients are making and compare them. There is obviously some difference in the requests.

Comment: request was the same in both cases: 
https://{address}/odata/$metadata#Roles